# Site hangs on Opera (Ubuntu)

Tags: support, status-norepro, opera, linux

The site (any of them) some times hangs when I am trying to post something (a question, an answer, a comment, or even a vote). Some times it also slows down the entire computer. The connection appears to have been lost and I am forced to open a new tab or restart the browser.

I am not experiencing these symptoms on other sites, nor on Chrome or Firefox. Has anyone had this problem?
I am using Opera 10.6 (Build 6386) on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: How is CPU usage? How is RAM usage? Do other tabs work? Is this reproducible with other browsers, operating systems, or computers on the same network? I've been using Chromium dev, Google Chrome, and Firefox in Ubuntu and haven't experienced any issues

Comment: I've had similar problems on Opera Mac, but have always attributed it to my known flaky connection.

Comment: Can't reproduce with Opera 10.70 build 6395 on Ubuntu 10.04 64bit, or with Opera 10.62 build 6438 on Ubuntu 10.04 32bit. Build 6438 seems to be the latest stable one in the official Opera Ubuntu repository (`deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ lenny non-free`), I'd suggest upgrading to that and see if problems persist - there have been many bugfixes between 10.60 and 10.62.

Comment: I am having issues with Opera, not only with SO. So I'll just use a different browser.

Answer (score 1):

I find it somehow hard to believe that a userspace process like Opera can cause a connection to be dropped (something opening a tab can magically fix!).

Just for fun, make sure Opera is not seeding any torrents, which may bring cheap or old router to their knees. You can find them in the download tab.

Sent using Opera 10.62 build 6438 on Ubuntu 10.10. It runs fine (although I still prefer Chromium nightlies.)

Comment: I much prefer Chrome too.

Comment: I meant it appears that Opera has lost connection to the Internet. My other browsers and apps still work fine.